# In Angular, is it possible to conditionally modify multiple HTML attributes with minimal repetition?

Tags: angular

I have the following block of template code in Angular 9, with a condition to show either a view (eye) icon or an edit (pencil) icon. As you can see, much of the HTML is identical, with only a few attributes and the click binding that are different.

```
<button *ngIf="!(hasEditAccess$ | async)" type="button" class="icon-button" (click)="entityViewClicked()" aria-label="View">
    <i class="far fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" title="View"></i>
</button>
<button *ngIf="hasEditAccess$ | async" type="button" class="icon-button" (click)="entityEditClicked()" aria-label="Edit">
    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true" title="Edit"></i>
</button>
```

Without creating a new component, is there a cleaner way to write this HTML and the conditional statement once, rather than repeating so much of it?

I'm thinking this may involve {{ interpolation }} syntax and some kind of template variable, but I welcome any approach that reduces the code duplication.

Comment: Ah, I had added an answer for using ng-container, but I had mis read your question. You have a lot of different properties that need to get changed so you would either have one button with conditionals on all the properties. or what you have now 2 separate buttons each in an ngIf.  I think this way is probably easier to read.

Comment: If you subscribe to same thing multiple times in template I would also multicast the observable. aka. `.pipe(share());`

Comment: @hyperdrive I've never used the `share()` operator before. I'll have to dig into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid repeating the condition with `*ngIf ... else`:

```
<button *ngIf="hasEditAccess$ | async; else viewButton" type="button" class="icon-button" (click)="entityEditClicked()" aria-label="Edit">
    <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt" aria-hidden="true" title="Edit"></i>
</button>
<ng-template #viewButton>
  <button type="button" class="icon-button" (click)="entityViewClicked()" aria-label="View">
      <i class="far fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" title="View"></i>
  </button>
</ng-template>
```

---

Now if you want to use a single button declaration to handle both "view" and "edit" scenarios, you can associate a variable to the `*ngIf` condition and use that variable in conditional bindings. In the example below, the click event is a common method `entityClicked` with a parameter indicating if it is used in an editing context.

```
<button *ngIf="hasEditAccess$ | async as canEdit" type="button" class="icon-button" 
  (click)="entityClicked(canEdit)" 
  [attr.aria-label]="canEdit ? 'Edit' : 'View'">
  <i aria-hidden="true" 
    [ngClass]="canEdit ? 'fas fa-pencil-alt' : 'far fa-eye'" 
    [title]="canEdit ? 'Edit' : 'View'"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Excellent! I knew about `else`, but didn't think it helped much with the duplication issue. However, I didn't know the `as` keyword could be used within an `*ngIf` to create a new variable reference. Thanks!